# Weird sum coming out of complex dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

Having trouble with this python code (dealing with data from midi files if you're curious about the variable names).

`song.getIntervals()` is a matrix of assorted integers, e.g.:

```
[[-2,0,0,5,3],[2],[4,3,0]]
```

except much longer.

`chrom` is defined as:

```
def createIntfunc(a,b):
    temp1={}
    temp2={}
    for x in range(a,b):
        temp1[x]=0
    for x in temp1:
        temp2[x]=dict(temp1)
    return temp2

chrom=createIntfunc(-17,18)
```

So it's a dictionary where the keys are integers and the values are dictionaries which have integers for both keys and values.

Here is the piece of code of concern:

```
for phrase in song.getIntervals():
    for noteind in range(1,len(phrase)):
        chrom[phrase[noteind-1]][phrase[noteind]]+=(1/float(sum([len(a) for a in song.getIntervals()])))
print sum([sum(a) for a in [b.values() for b in chrom.values()]])
```

which prints a value that's close to 0.8 depending on what song.getIntervals() is. But I don't see how it wouldn't just always return 1.  Essentially I'm repeatedly adding to a value that starts at zero a fraction that's defined as the inverse of however many times I'm going to add it.  So that should be 0+(1/x)*x=1.

What am I not seeing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is your problem:

Your value of "1/x" is not actually getting added "x" times, because the inside of your loop is not running "x" times.  For example, when the length of a phrase is only 1, "1/x" is not added into the dictionary, because the inner loop only runs on indices which satisfy the inequality 1 <= noteind < len(phrase).  When len(phrase)==1, no index can satisfy this inequality, so the inside of the loop doesn't execute.  I'm not sure what your intention is for this to do, so I'm not sure exactly how to fix it without knowing the intended behavior, but that's why it's performing the way it is.